# Android 2.2 - ActionBar alternative - Method to change Views?

Tags: android

I can't get ActionBarSherlock to work, I'll get tons of errors and I don't know really how to do it...

So I ask if there was an alternative to the Action Bar, or a cool, easy way (for the user) to change a view...

Thanks.

Here's (one) ABS Error:

```
...
[2012-07-06 12:01:45 - ANDA] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that the `android-support-v4.jar` in your project is clashing with the one in ABS. Try and delete `android-support-v4.jar` from the `/libs/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting dependency issues is that ActionBar was introduced for Android 3.0 and above but you are developing for Android 2.2 I believe. So, you can't have the ActionBar in your Android 2.2 application.

But if you indeed do need to use the ActionBar, then try this awesome API : http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Sample AndroidManifest.xml for SherlockActionBar :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.test.sherlock"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    <activity android:name=".SherlockSimpleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Otherwise, how about using Tabs to switch the views?
I suggest that you use TabHost to dynamically change a view. Have a look at the documentation  : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

If you want a step by step approach to it, check this tutorial out : 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

Comment: I'm already using ActionBarSherlock for my 2.2 App but it shows me tons of errors...

Comment: If you’re using the Eclipse Development Environment with the ADT plugin version 0.9.7 or greater you can include ActionBarSherlock as a library project. Create a new Android project in Eclipse using the library/ folder as the existing source. Then, in your project properties, add the created project under the ‘Libraries’ section of the ‘Android’ category.

Comment: I did this but the ActionBar isn't showing up... Now I don't get any errors and I changed the Activity to SherlockActivity... The App starts but there's no "Button" to press on the ActionBar.

Comment: Please check my edited answer. I have added the code for the sample AndroidManifest.xml file. I guess that you must be missing the theme for which the buttons are not showing.